# Which of these two options would have the lower cost?

Tags: solidity, gas

I'm quite new to solidity, and I was wondering which one of the two following solutions would have the lower cost in terms of gas fee. As I said, being new to this world if you have any suggestions on how to improve the code I'm well open to new options...
So, I want to take note on my contract of people who interact with it and at the first "login" give them 10 coins, obviusly I need to check if they have already logged or not.

First attempt

```
struct User {
        bool logged;
        uint8 coins;
        address userAddress;
    }

User[] public users;

function registration(address _user) public {
     require(!users[msg.sender].logged, "User already logged");
     users.push(User(true, 10, _user));
}
```

or

```
mapping(address => bool) private _usersLogged;
mapping(address => uint8) public _users;


function register(address _user) public {
    require(!_usersLogged[msg.sender], "User already registered");
    _users[_user] = 10;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an estimateGas function attached to every Contract method, that could be helpful for you to test the real cost of the transaction, without having to execute it.

You can test it from frontend, with javascript, using different frameworks:

**With Ethers**
https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-estimateGas

**With Web3.js**
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas